# we've ever had as a company?

Tags: phrases

> We now have the best cars and trucks we’ve ever had as a company

The last part of the sentence, "as a company", is confusing. Please help me what this sentence means. Does it mean

> We now have the cars and trucks as a corporation, and it is the best
>   we've ever had.

or

> We now have the best cars and trucks we've ever had in our company
>   history.

?

Comment: It's something along these lines: individuals in the company might have had better cars, but the *company* (as a separate entity) hasn't.

Comment: @Lawrence: That's one possible interpretation. Another is *Although we never had the best vehicles before (back when we were just  a **partnership**, perhaps, with less favourable tax breaks), **now that we're a company** we can and do indulge ourselves with the best.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed - regardless of the merits of vehicles other associated entities (individuals, corporate structures, etc) owned, the current set is the best the *company* has ever owned.

Comment: @Lawrence: Not even that is certain. Perhaps they used to be a partnership as before, but they **bought** (and thus "became") a pre- existing company that once had a real luxury fleet. (Which the company couldn't afford, obviously, so it was a failing business going cheap for the partnership to buy up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your second example, don't separate "best" from "cars and trucks". It means that currently they have the best cars and trucks that they have ever had.

Your first example implies that some company that never had "cars and trucks" (or had lousy ones) has purchased (or been given) some, and now either the company or their life (circumstances) is the best it's ever been.